# What has happened to python-serial?

Tags: python

I have had replace an old PI2B, Jessie, Python 2.7, which satisfactorily ran some python code, with PI3B, Buster, Python 3.7, but I now cannot find/load python-serial. 'sudo apt-get install python-serial' installs it but when my python code is run it reports it as missing and 'sudo pip install python-serial' can't install it and comes back with the error below. Has it been replaced/superseded? What can I do to enable 'import serial' to work? Thanks

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
> Collecting python-serial
> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: [https://pypi.org/simple/python-serial/"](https://pypi.org/simple/python-serial/%22)
> Blockquote

Comment: looks like it has been replaced by pySerial

Comment: add what linux distribution you are working on. the library is `pyserial` but the name to install changes depending on the platform: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html

Answer (score 0):

Python 2's `python-serial` is Python 3's `python3-serial` (note the `python3`) It can be installed from buster repositories as of this post.

It can also be installed from `pip` here:

```sh
pip3 install pyserial
```

If pip is not available on the machine then it can be installed from source:

https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/releases

Download the archive, extract it and install it with:

```sh
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks I used pip3 and had this response. `Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` which puzzles me as my Python code was saying it could not `import serial` ?                           (3.5)

Comment: @PeterHeater - I had an issue when trying to get this to work as there was another package with the "serial" name already installed. I needed to remove debian package `python3-serial` and pip package `serial` for it to read the pip package `pyserial`

Comment: Thanks, I will see how I can remove them, and looks like I won't have to alter my Python code.

Comment: Thanks again. python3-seriaI removed but pip uninstall reported not found, but still have the cannot `import serial` error so there must be an old copy still about. How can I track it down?

Comment: instead of importing `serial` try `import pyserial as serial`

Comment: Thanks, I was hopeful that would fix it it now says cannot find pyserial when it has been loaded? ` File "/usr/local/Djuke/PreampClient.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyserial as serial
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyserial'
volumio@pnbvolumio:~$ pip3 install pyserial
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.5)